# Is it "quit" or "quitted"?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, past-participles, simple-past

What is the correct (grammatical) simple past and past participle form of the verb *quit*? Is it *quit* or *quitted*?

> She *quitted* her job. (She *has quitted* her job.)

> She *quit* her job. (She *has quit* her job.)

Comment: American English or British English?

Comment: If it differs, both.

Comment: "Quitted" as that simple past for "quit" is very rare in the United States.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I would use *quit*, as it is more readily understood by people. [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quit) indicates that both are plausible. [Merriam Webster](http://mw1.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quitted) says the same.

Looking through Google books, [*quitted*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22quitted%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1806&lr=lang_en) seems to be used synonymously with left, e.g.,

> Plato quitted Athens, where he was adored as a god ...
>   I quitted Manchester, I quitted Mrs. ++++++++, I quitted ++++++++ hall ...
>   ... you have not quitted the path of virtue ...

Although this usage seems to have declined markedly. This can be seen in a Google NGram, as found by FumbleFingers:

[image: "had quitted" vs "had quit"]

Comment: I think [this chart for "had quitted/had quit"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+quitted%2Chad+quit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows clearly that *quitted* was the standard past tense until the mid-1900s. It seems to be one of those relatively rare cases where a regular verb changes to become "irregular".

Answer (score 14):

The OED records both as alternatives for the past tense and the past participle.